# Complementary p values do not cancel in many combining methods – why is this not a big deal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, combining-p-values

#### What is this about?

Suppose I have performed two statistical tests (with a continuous distribution of $p$ values) for the same one-sided research hypothesis on different datasets, yielding the $p$ values $p_1=x$ and $p_2=1-x$.
I have no further a priori knowledge that makes a distinction between the datasets, e.g., to weigh them.
In this case, I do not learn anything from my tests as to whether my research hypothesis is true or not.
If I tested the opposite research hypothesis, I would obtain the same results (just in different order).
Therefore the accurate result for combining these $p$ values is $p_\text{comb} = \frac{1}{2}$.

However many methods for combining $p$ values do not treat $p$ values and their complements in a symmetrical fashion and produce implausible results.
For example for $x=0.01$:

- Fisher’s method: $p_\text{comb} = 0.06$
- Pearson’s method: $p_\text{comb} = 0.94$
- Tippett’s method: $p_\text{comb} = 0.02$
- Simes’ method: $p_\text{comb} = 0.02$

By contrast, Stouffer’s method, Mudholkar’s and George’s method, as well as Edgington’s method are symmetric (as described above) and produce $p_\text{comb} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Obviously, this problem extends beyond the above simple example and can lead to many clear false positives in many cases. I could probably produce datasets where two opposing one-side research hypotheses are both highly significant.

#### My question

I consider it a serious flaw of a combining method if complementary $p$ values do not cancel each other.
However, I fail to find this issue mentioned in the literature on combining $p$ values.
To give just one example, the paper [*Choosing Between Methods of Combining $p$-values*](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asx076) does not mention it as far as I can tell.
In fact, the only mention I have found so far is [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asx076) on this site.

So, **what am I missing?**

- Is there literature on this (and I failed to find it)?
- Is my argument somehow flawed and I am overestimating the importance of this?
- Is this generally accepted, but just not documented?

Comment: This is another way of looking at the well-known fact that a two-tailed test from a meta-analysis may be designed to furnish a low p-value when results from different studies significantly depart from the null in different directions. Take the simple case of testing for a difference in means: would you still cling to the null hypothesis of a common, zero say, effect when you have a dozen studies showing a large increase & a dozen showing a large decrease?

Comment: @Scortchi: Either I misunderstand you or these are not comparable. Here I look at one-sided tests for the same direction, i.e., deviations from the null in different directions are properly distinguished in the individual tests. In fact, something similar to your last example may have been underlying my example (just with one study each, not a dozen): You have one study showing a large decrease and one showing a large increase (of same significance). (Of course, if I had dozens of each, I would probably conclude that something is horribly wrong, but I still cannot say anything about my trend.)

Comment: It's the same kettle of fish. If you encompass study heterogeneity in your alternative hypothesis, then there's nothing counter-intuitive about observing low p-values for both one-tailed tests; if you rule it out as a possibility then you need to choose a test that isn't sensitive to it (though of course risking an additional assumption violation).

Comment: I see. However, this directly poses the question (at least to me) why anybody would work with such a hypothesis in the first place. Also I wonder whether one can formulate better null/alternative hypotheses that reflect a consistent trend (or absence thereof).

Comment: "If I tested the opposite research hypothesis, I would obtain the same results (just in different order)." I might not be understanding you, but I do not think this is strictly true. For example, if you failed to reject $\text{H}_0 \text{: } \mu \ge c $, is that because $\mu \ge c$, or because your data do not have enough power for **that** null? It is quite possible that you could either reject or fail to reject a different null hypothesis, $\text{H}_0\text{: }\mu \le c$, on the same data.

Comment: @Alexis: This is not about any different null hypothesis, but the one corresponding to the opposite research hypothesis. For a (one-sided, continuous) test/hypothesis with reasonable symmetry (so yes: not strictly always), this will have the complementary $p$ value. For example, if the $p$ value of the left-tailed $t$ test for a given dataset is $x$, then the $p$ value for the respective right-tailed test is $1-x$.

Comment: Well, testing by combining p-values is the most rudimentary/preliminary kind of meta-analysis. All the same, there's nothing weird about wanting to test the sharp null $H_0: \tau_1=\tau_2=0 $ vs the alternative $H_\mathrm{A}: \tau_1 >0 \lor \tau_2 >0$ - think of say a two- way ANOVAR with interaction. In some cases it may be reasonable to assume a common treatment effect & to test $H_0: \tau =0$ vs $H_\mathrm{A}:\tau>1$; in others perhaps to test the weak null $H_0: \bar{\tau} = 0$ vs $H_\mathrm{A}: \bar{\tau} > 0$. Horses for courses.

Comment: @Scortchi: I get why you would perform two-sided tests and ANOVA in general, but not why you would combine them. More to the point, I fail to imagine an application behind the scenario depicted in the question where you would consider a combined *p* value other than ½ an appropriate result, i.e., where you really only care about any one-sided single test result being significant, irrespective of whether the other test is significant in the other direction. (But maybe this is material for another question.) — As for your other examples, I am afraid I don’t get what you are aiming at.

Comment: Suppose you're looking at a collection of studies that investigate the use of vitamin C as a prophylatic against the common cold. They're quite diverse in their methods & subjects - one prescribes doses of 3 grams per day to Brazilian army recruits during basic training, another 60 milligrams per day to Norwegian care home residents over a year, & so on - you've not much reason to expect the effect to be similar across studies - perhaps it even increases the risk of catching a cold under some circumstances -, & it's hard to see to what population the average ...

Comment: ... effect across studies would be relevant. But you're still interested in whether *there are* circumstances, people, & regimens for which the treatment might work. If you use Stouffer's method for combining p-values; a few studies with large effects can be drowned among many with negligible effects (or netted off against studies with effects in the opposite direction; if you use Bonferroni's method you discount any accumulation of small effects: Fisher's method is a kind of compromise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure when the methods were first systematically compared but Loughin in a paper entitled "A systematic comparison of methods for combining p-values from independent tests" available [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947303002950) compared some of them. He does refer to previous work which discussed the issue you raise. Some other methods are compared in my R package [metap](https://cran.r-project.org/package=metap) and the comparisons set out in one of the vignettes. (Apologies for the self-promotion.)

I am not an expert on modern genetics but I believe that there the interest is in which tests display the signal and so a method which does not cancel is quite acceptable and indeed even preferred.

As you suggest plotting the $p$-values should really be obligatory as then it becomes clear that there are extreme values in both directions which should lead the investigator to question their theory. I am not aware of substantial sources recommending this though.